# Ajax request from localhost to another server on the same wifi

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, rest, intellij-idea

A few questions over here actually, under different scenarios.

So I am connected to the same wifi as a RESTful server is hosted.

I opened a webpage in IntelliJ and it created a localhost server on my machine so that it can start up my webcam. (When I try to open the webpage from my file directory, the webcam does not start up)

I am trying to do an ajax request that looks like this.

```
$.ajax({

            url: 'http://192.xxx.x.xx:xxxx/restful/webapi/enroll',
            //url: 'http://localhost:63xxx/example-1.0.0.0-samples/',
            type: 'PUT',
            contentType: "application/json",
            processData: false,
            data: data,
            dataType: 'json',
            crossDomain:true,
            error: function (xhr, status) {
                if(xhr.status != "201"){ // 201 means it is Created, rather than 200 which means Success
                    $("#statusEnrollmentMsg").text("Fail " + status);
                    console.log(error);
                }else{
                    $("#textbox").text("success");  
                }
            },
            success: function (result) {
                $("#textbox").text("success");
            }
        });
```

Error code

```
    jquery.min.js:4 OPTIONS http://192.xxx.x.xx:xxxx/restful/webapi/enroll 
    send @ jquery.min.js:4
    ajax @ jquery.min.js:4
    OnEnroll @ example.js:130
    onclick @ example.html:54
    example.html:1 
    XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://192.xxx.x.xx:xxxx/restful/webapi/enroll. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
    Origin 'http://localhost:63xxx' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.
```

Im always getting error that looks like this.
If it is not clear kindly comment and I will make adjustments.

cross domain has been set to true already!

I want to send some json object to this server. I am not sure if this is the proper protocol too. Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

Check documentation : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

> crossDomain (default: false for same-domain requests, true for
>   cross-domain requests)
>
> Type: Boolean
>
> If you wish to force a crossDomain request (such as JSONP) on the same
>   domain, set the value of crossDomain to true. This allows, for
>   example, server-side redirection to another domain. (version added:
>   1.5)

Your Code should be like this

```
$.ajax({

            url: 'http://192.xxx.x.xx:xxxx/restful/webapi/enroll',
            type: 'PUT',
            crossDomain: true,
            contentType: "application/json",
            processData: false,
            data: data,
            dataType: 'json',
            crossDomain:true,
            error: function (xhr, status) {
                if(xhr.status != "201"){ // 201 means it is Created, rather than 200 which means Success
                    $("#statusEnrollmentMsg").text("Fail " + status);
                    console.log(error);
                }else{
                    $("#textbox").text("success");  
                }
            },
            success: function (result) {
                $("#textbox").text("success");
            }
        });
```

Comment: Which the crossDomain has already been set to true! whats the difference between your code and mine? I dont see it tho, sorry!

Comment: Ohh sorry, try with GET/POST method if its working then you have to modify header in AJAX request.

Comment: sorry, what is header? I tried with a POST request and I got back the same error

Comment: Hi how do I modify the header?